# How to understand Quiescent Consistency?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, sequential, consistency

I am reading 'The Art of Multiprocessor Programming'. Now, i get stuck at third chapter , because do not understand the notion of Quiescent Consistency.Can you give me a example to expain what is Quiescent Consistency?Please as clearly as possible!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In distributed programming, there is an approach to describe data
>   structure behavior known as quiescent consistency. There is a number
>   of consistency conditions, sequential consistency, linearizability and
>   others. These conditions describe how an object behaves when there are
>   several threads calling its methods.
>
> A data structure possesses quiescent consistency if it is consistent
>   between its states of quiescence, i.e. when there are no methods
>   currently in progress. As soon as a quiescently consistent structure
>   has no operations pending (i.e. reaches the quiescence), we may be
>   sure that the executions of methods before this state and after this
>   state is never interpositioned.
>
> An execution is quiescently consistent if the method calls can be
>   correctly arranged retaining the mutual order of calls separated by
>   quiescence, a period of time where no method is being called in any
>   thread.

[image]

Sources:
http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/88
http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/72